# Bitrix создание элемента инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Как в CMS битрикс через код добавить элемент инфоблока? пробовал вот так, при инициализации белый экран:

```
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");?>

<?php
$el = new CIBlockElement::Add;
$p = $el->Add([
    'MODIFIED_BY' => $USER->GetID(),
    'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID' => false,
    'IBLOCK_ID' => 9,
    'PROPERTY_VALUES' => [],
    'NAME' => 'Тестовый элемент #1',
    'ACTIVE' => 'Y',
    'PREVIEW_TEXT' => 'Мини-текст',
    'DETAIL_TEXT' => 'Полный текст',
    'DETAIL_PICTURE' => 'https://lizasenglish.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Tests.png'
]);
?>

<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас синтаксическая ошибка. Замените `$el = new CIBlockElement::Add;` на `$el = new CIBlockElement();` и перед этой строчкой подключите модуль Информационных блоков `CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');`